# "No suitable driver found..." with Derby 10.15.1.3 under Java 8

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, derby

I'm trying to push the datas from Java class Restaurants2 to the SQL database based in derby using the Maven software.

The idea was that the Java class will add a few informations to the DB at Derby database "MyDB".

Unfortunately I cannot run this program because of Exception (please see also below the information from console).
I'm working with Eclipse 4.12.0 on the MacOS Mojave.
Does anybody know what's wrong?
Cheers!

```
    Java class Restaurants2: 

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;



    public class Restaurants2
    {

    // jdbc:derby:/Users/ap/MyDB;create=true
    private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:/Users/ap/MyDB/;create=true;user=***;password=***";
    private static String tableName = " MYTABELLE2";
    // jdbc Connection
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        createConnection();
        insertRestaurants(5, "LaVals", "Berkeley");
        selectRestaurants();
        shutdown();
    }

    private static void createConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void insertRestaurants(int id, String restName, String cityName)
    {
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("insert into " + tableName + " values (" +
                    id + ",'" + restName + "','" + cityName +"')");
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void selectRestaurants()
    {
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = results.getMetaData();
            int numberCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i=1; i<=numberCols; i++)
            {
                //print Column Names
                System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)+"\t\t");  
            }

            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

            while(results.next())
            {
                int id = results.getInt(1);
                String restName = results.getString(2);
                String cityName = results.getString(3);
                System.out.println(id + "\t\t" + restName + "\t\t" + cityName);
            }
            results.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void shutdown()
    {
        try
        {
            if (stmt != null)
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
            {
                DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
                conn.close();
            }           
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

The program doesn't run and I get the information from console that there are Exceptions:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at Restaurants2.createConnection(Restaurants2.java:40)
at Restaurants2.main(Restaurants2.java:30)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Restaurants2.insertRestaurants(Restaurants2.java:54)
at Restaurants2.main(Restaurants2.java:31)`
```

This is how looks like my dependency from POM file:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
<artifactId>derby</artifactId>
<version>10.14.2.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
<artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
<version>10.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Seems you are missing the driver libraries for derby in the classpath. Maybe this one? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbyclient

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but I have it in my dependencies....

Comment: @leccepen - What does `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` display?

Comment: Hi @Gord Thompson, the output for Java version is 1.8.0_212. Cheers

Comment: If you are 100% sure that the driver is properly loaded than you must have an invalid connection URL.

Comment: I am not an expert on derby but i think the URL should just end with the DB name not with a table name.

Comment: What happens if you change 

`private static String dbURL = 
"jdbc:derby:/Users/ap/MyDB/Schemas/MYKILLERAPP/Tables/MyTabelle2;create=true;user=***;password=***";`

**TO**

`private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:databaseServerURL:port/databasename;create=true;user=***;password=***";`

Answer (score 2):

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
<artifactId>derby</artifactId>
<version>10.15.1.3</version>
```

> the output for Java version is 1.8.0_212

Starting with version 10.15.x, Derby requires Java 9 or newer (ref: [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/cgsintsr.html)).

If you want to continue using Java 8 you will have to downgrade Derby to version 10.14.2.0.

Comment: I have already had the same idea and changed to 10.14.2.0 but still I get Exception please see my post already has been edited...

Comment: Remove `<scope>test</scope>` from your dependency declaration.

Comment: The I get error that 'TEST' does not exist:     ´java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:  
    'TEST' doesn't exist. at 
    org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown 
    Source).´

Comment: If you no longer get "No suitable driver found" or `ClassNotFoundException` then your connection issue has been resolved and now you are facing a different problem. You should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that.